# WkHtmlToXSharp crush when using multi threading

Tags: c#, asp.net, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to change multiple HTML files to PDF using WkHtmlToXSharp.
The problem is , when I put 1 file in folder , all works fine.
When I try putting number of files , the application just crush and stop working... (the content of the files is similar , so its not a problem with file content).

Any idea what might cause this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the MultiplexingConverter class? If not you have to handle all the multithreading yourself by queuing the conversions.  I believe it's outlined in the readme, but it's much easier to just use the provided class.